# Change tint of SFSymbol in UITableView Cell Accessory tvOS

Tags: cocoa, uiimageview, uiimage, highlight, tvos

I am adding an accessory view to a cell with:

```
UIImageSymbolConfiguration* configuration = [UIImageSymbolConfiguration configurationWithPointSize:28 weight:UIImageSymbolWeightRegular];
UIImageView* accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"globe" withConfiguration:configuration]] autorelease];

[accessoryView setImage:[imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];
[accessoryView setTintColor:[UIColor labelColor]];

[cell setAccessoryView: accessoryView];
```

This works, but how can I configure it so that when the cell is highlighted, the globe icon changes from the labelColor tint to black (so it matches the text color)?

I have also tried making a highlighted image but it does not have any effect:

```
UIImageSymbolConfiguration* configuration = [UIImageSymbolConfiguration configurationWithPointSize:28 weight:UIImageSymbolWeightRegular];
UIImageView* accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"globe" withConfiguration:configuration]] autorelease];

UIImage* normalImage = [accessoryView.image imageWithTintColor:[UIColor labelColor]];
UIImage* highlightImage = [accessoryView.image imageWithTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[accessoryView setImage:normalImage];
[accessoryView setHighlightedImage:highlightImage];

[cell setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
```

Furthermore, the highlighted image never seems to be used at all:

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"checkmark" withConfiguration:configuration] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIImage* highlightedImage = [[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"globe" withConfiguration:configuration] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

UIImageView* accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image highlightedImage:highlightedImage] autorelease];
[cell setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
```

In the above code, the highlighted image is never shown.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    NSIndexPath* nextPath = [context nextFocusedIndexPath];
    if (nextPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextPath];
        UIImageView* accessoryView = (UIImageView *)[cell accessoryView];
        [accessoryView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }

    NSIndexPath* prevPath = [context previouslyFocusedIndexPath];
    if (prevPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:prevPath];
        UIImageView* accessoryView = (UIImageView *)[cell accessoryView];
        [accessoryView setTintColor:[UIColor labelColor]];
    }
}
```